# Running total not lining up with GrandTotal

Tags: sql

I am working on the below query and running into a problem. The query runs and returns the values but the running total does not match up with the GrandTotal.

As an example:

GrandTotal: 1 + 1 = 2 Running Total = 2

GrandTotal: 1 + 2 = 3 Running Total = 4

GrandTotal: 1 + 3 = 3 Running Total = 6

It seems like my Grandtotal Column is not lining up with my running total. Is there a way to sync them? For example can I make the GrandTotal column be in descending order and have the running total start at row 1?

Here is my query:

```
Select *

CASE 
WHEN RunningTotal <=95000000 THEN 'A'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 95000001 AND 1449750000   THEN 'B' 

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 144975000 AND 164974500   THEN 'C'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 164974500 AND 184974000 THEN 'D'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 184974000 AND 189673500 THEN 'E'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 189673500 AND 192173000 THEN 'F'

WHEN RunningTotal >=1921730000 THEN 'G'



End as 'Case_column'

 FROM

(SELECT column1, column2, column3
, column4 ,column5,column6,
column7,
column8,column9,
column10,column11,column12
, (coalesce(column6,0)      
+ coalesce(column7,0)
+ coalesce(column8,0)
+ coalesce(olumn9,0)
+ coalesce(column10,0)
+ coalesce(Scolumn11,0)
+ coalesce(column12,0)
) AS GrandTotal



, SUM(coalesce(column6,0)      
+ coalesce(column7,0)
+ coalesce(column8,0)
+ coalesce(olumn9,0)
+ coalesce(column10,0)
+ coalesce(Scolumn11,0)
+ coalesce(column12,0)) 
           OVER(ORDER BY column1 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS RunningTotal 
FROM datav2 WHERE column BETWEEN '2021-03-09' AND '2021-03-09') sub

ORDER BY RunningTotal ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
Order by Column1
```

instead of

```
ORDER BY RunningTotal ASC
```

It might make your runningtotal line up with grand total in ascending order of column1.

And in where clause I think column name is wrong. Please check it out. It might be a typo

```
WHERE column BETWEEN '2021-03-09' AND '2021-03-09'
```

If you want your output table in descending order of grandtotal and want the running total column to follow this order you can use below query:

```
with sub as
(SELECT column1, column2, column3
, column4 ,column5,column6,
column7,
column8,column9,
column10,column11,column12
, (coalesce(column6,0)      
+ coalesce(column7,0)
+ coalesce(column8,0)
+ coalesce(olumn9,0)
+ coalesce(column10,0)
+ coalesce(Scolumn11,0)
+ coalesce(column12,0)
) AS GrandTotal 

           
FROM datav2 WHERE column1 BETWEEN '2021-03-09' AND '2021-03-09'),
runningtotals as (select *,sum(GrandTotal)OVER(ORDER BY GrandTotal desc
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS RunningTotal  from sub)

Select *,

CASE 
WHEN RunningTotal <=95000000 THEN 'A'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 95000001 AND 1449750000   THEN 'B' 

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 144975000 AND 164974500   THEN 'C'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 164974500 AND 184974000 THEN 'D'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 184974000 AND 189673500 THEN 'E'

WHEN RunningTotal BETWEEN 189673500 AND 192173000 THEN 'F'

WHEN RunningTotal >=1921730000 THEN 'G'



End as 'Case_column'

 FROM runningtotals
```

** Please look into the where clause. Please check whether the column name **column** or it's been misspelled.

Comment: I might not be understanding your comment, but I think I did use a sum ?


`**SUM**(coalesce(column6,0)      

+ coalesce(column7,0)

+ coalesce(column8,0)

+ coalesce(olumn9,0)
+ coalesce(column10,0)
+ coalesce(Scolumn11,0)
+ coalesce(column12,0)) 
           OVER(ORDER BY column1 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS RunningTotal`

Comment: extremely sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: is it possible to share sample data?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The data is all private work stuff.    Is there more details I can give to help with a solution?

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know your feedback.